# Python: Random selection per group

Tags: python, random, pandas

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Name Group_Id
AAA  1
ABC  1
CCC  2
XYZ  2
DEF  3 
YYH  3
```

How could I randomly select one (or more) row for each `Group_Id`? Say that I want one random draw per `Group_Id`, I would get:

```
Name Group_Id
AAA  1
XYZ  2
DEF  3
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
size = 2        # sample size
replace = True  # with replacement
fn = lambda obj: obj.loc[np.random.choice(obj.index, size, replace),:]
df.groupby('Group_Id', as_index=False).apply(fn)
```

Comment: set replace=False if you don't want to get the same row per group twice.

Comment: If you do this with a timestamp column where you create a frequency based pd.Grouper(),  the proposed method yields two identically named timestamp index columns. Less than ideal situation. Also see below where I've posted a far more simpler (less code, easier to remember, less complexity in general) method to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 65):

From `0.16.x` onwards [`pd.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) provides a way to return a random sample of items from an axis of object.

```
In [664]: df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[664]:
  Name  Group_Id
0  ABC         1
1  XYZ         2
2  DEF         3
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=1).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 19):

There are two ways to do this very simply, one without using anything except basic pandas syntax:

```
df[['x','y']].groupby('x').agg(pd.DataFrame.sample)
```

This takes 14.4ms with 50k row dataset.

The other, slightly faster method, involves numpy.

```
df[['x','y']].groupby('x').agg(np.random.choice)
```

This takes 10.9ms with (the same) 50k row dataset.

Generally speaking, when using pandas, it's preferable to stick with its native syntax. Especially for beginners.

Comment: this is the most pandaeic answer, but how does it possibly generalize to sampling `n` items per group? :-)

Comment: @matanster `agg` didn't work for me, but `apply` did. It can also take arguments for the function: `df[['x','y']].groupby('x').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=n, replace=False)`. See docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

Comment: This method will make a different random selection from each column in each group, rather than selecting the entire row in each group.

The answer from @ihadanny will select entire rows, and is faster.

Answer (score 17):

```
df.groupby('Group_Id').sample(n=1)
```

New in version 1.1.0.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html

Comment: I believe you have to add the random_state to make it work.

Comment: Based on the DataFrame.GroupBy.sample [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html), `RANDOM_STATE` can be used to guarantee reproducibility. Group-wise shuffling set parameter `frac=1` as ```df.groupby("Group_Id").sample(frac=1, random_state=1)```

Answer (score 11):

Using groupby and random.choice in an elegant one liner:

```
df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(lambda x :x.iloc[random.choice(range(0,len(x)))])
```

Comment: `random.choice(range(0,len(x)))` is better written as `np.random.randint(0, len(x))`

Comment: There might be a slight preference from some people to use numpy.random.choice, which allows you to specify a) the number of samples to take from the population and b) if you want replacement. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: `df.sample(frac = 1.0).groupby('Group_Id').head(1)` is so much faster

Comment: @ihadanny's suggestion is more 'pandaeic' and also generalizes to n>1, although being slower than the [other answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674575/1509695)

Answer (score 11):

for randomly selecting just one row per group try:

```
df.sample(frac = 1.0).groupby('Group_Id').head(1)
```

Comment: This is the fastest answer, and it works for selecting rows that span multiple columns.

Answer (score 9):

The solutions offered fail if a group has fewer samples than the desired sample size `n`. This addresses this problem:

```
n = 10
df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(n,len(x)))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

A very pandas-ish way:

```
takesamp = lambda d: d.sample(n)
df = df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(takesamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `random.choice`, you can do something like this:

```
import random
name_group = {'AAA': 1, 'ABC':1, 'CCC':2, 'XYZ':2, 'DEF':3, 'YYH':3}

names = [name for name in name_group.iterkeys()] #create a list out of the keys in the name_group dict

first_name = random.choice(names)
first_group = name_group[first_name]
print first_name, first_group
```

> `random.choice(seq)`
>
> ```
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`pandas.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) and [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['AAA', 'ABC', 'CCC', 'XYZ', 'DEF', 'YYH'],
        'Group_ID': [1,1,2,2,3,3]
     })

grouped = df.groupby('Group_ID')
df_sampled = pd.concat([d.ix[random.sample(d.index, 1)] for _, d in grouped]).reset_index(drop=True)
print df_sampled
```

Output:

```
   Group_ID Name
0         1  AAA
1         2  XYZ
2         3  DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another one:

```
size=2
count_s = df['Id'].value_counts()
df.iloc[np.concatenate([previous_count + np.random.choice(count, size) 
                        for count, previous_count in zip(count_s, 
                                                         count_s.shift(fill_value=0))])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sample` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sample(frac = 1.0).drop_duplicates('Group_Id', ignore_index=True)
```