# Pandas dataframe random row selection per group with a boolean condition

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, group-by

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Dave','Lisa','John',Lisa','Simon','Simon','Simon','Simon','Lisa','Dave','Dave','John','Lisa'],
'date': ['2015-01-31 07:14:39','2014-12-16 22:50:55','2015-04-12 23:29:11','2015-04-08 17:57:29','2015-01-30 03:51:12','2015-02-20 10:33:48','2014-12-15 23:54:03','2014-12-16 19:53:53','2014-12-18 00:15:02','2015-04-01 21:36:55','2015-04-13 23:25:55','2015-02-18 14:10:40','2015-02-27 04:56:33']})
```

DATAFRAME1

```
            date            name
0   2015-01-31 07:14:39     Dave
1   2014-12-16 22:50:55     Lisa
2   2015-04-12 23:29:11     John
3   2015-04-08 17:57:29     Lisa
4   2015-01-30 03:51:12     Simon
5   2015-02-20 10:33:48     Simon
6   2014-12-15 23:54:03     Simon
7   2014-12-16 19:53:53     Simon
8   2014-12-18 00:15:02     Lisa
9   2015-04-01 21:36:55     Dave
10  2015-04-13 23:25:55     Dave
11  2015-02-18 14:10:40     John
12  2015-02-27 04:56:33     Lisa
```

DATAFRAME2

```
    name           datemax
0   Dave    2015-04-13 23:25:55
1   John    2015-04-12 23:29:11
2   Lisa    2015-04-08 17:57:29
3   Simon   2015-02-20 10:33:48
```

where the 'date' and 'datemax' columns are filled with datetime objects.

I need to group by 'name' in DATAFRAME1 choosing randomly one of the dates, but I want this chosen date to come before the 'datemax' for that name in the second dataframe (DATAFRAME2).

The real dataframe I'm working on is way bigger than the one of this example, so I need a quick way to do this.

Comment: Does it need to be random, or could it be the first valid date?

Comment: It need to be random :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first splice out all the dates which don't satisfy that criteria:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("name")["date"].transform(lambda x: df2a.loc[x.name, "datemax"])
Out[11]:
0    2015-04-13 23:25:55
1    2015-04-08 17:57:29
2    2015-04-12 23:29:11
3    2015-04-08 17:57:29
4    2015-02-20 10:33:48
5    2015-02-20 10:33:48
6    2015-02-20 10:33:48
7    2015-02-20 10:33:48
8    2015-04-08 17:57:29
9    2015-04-13 23:25:55
10   2015-04-13 23:25:55
11   2015-04-12 23:29:11
12   2015-04-08 17:57:29
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [12]: df["date"] < df.groupby("name")["date"].transform(lambda x: df2a.loc[x.name, "datemax"])
Out[12]:
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
11     True
12     True
Name: date, dtype: bool

In [13]: df_old = df[df["date"] < df.groupby("name")["date"].transform(lambda x: df2a.loc[x.name, "datemax"])]

In [14]: df_old
Out[14]:
                  date   name
0  2015-01-31 07:14:39   Dave
1  2014-12-16 22:50:55   Lisa
4  2015-01-30 03:51:12  Simon
6  2014-12-15 23:54:03  Simon
7  2014-12-16 19:53:53  Simon
8  2014-12-18 00:15:02   Lisa
9  2015-04-01 21:36:55   Dave
11 2015-02-18 14:10:40   John
12 2015-02-27 04:56:33   Lisa
```

Now it becomes a much easier problem: [pick a random row by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22472213/1240268):

```
df_old.groupby("name").agg(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.randint(0,len(x))])

In [21]: df_old.groupby("name").agg(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.randint(0,len(x))])
Out[21]:
                     date
name
Dave  2015-04-01 21:36:55
John  2015-02-18 14:10:40
Lisa  2014-12-16 22:50:55
Simon 2014-12-15 23:54:03

In [22]: df_old.groupby("name").agg(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.randint(0,len(x))])
Out[22]:
                     date
name
Dave  2015-01-31 07:14:39
John  2015-02-18 14:10:40
Lisa  2014-12-18 00:15:02
Simon 2014-12-16 19:53:53
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:

```
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Dave','Lisa','John','Lisa','Simon','Simon','Simon','Simon','Lisa','Dave','Dave','John','Lisa'],'date': ['2015-01-31 07:14:39','2014-12-16 22:50:55','2015-04-12 23:29:11','2015-04-08 17:57:29','2015-01-30 03:51:12','2015-02-20 10:33:48','2014-12-15 23:54:03','2014-12-16 19:53:53','2014-12-18 00:15:02','2015-04-01 21:36:55','2015-04-13 23:25:55','2015-02-18 14:10:40','2015-02-27 04:56:33']})

df.date = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in df.date]

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Dave','2015-04-13 23:25:55'],['John','2015-04-12 23:29:11'],['Lisa','2015-04-08 17:57:29'],['Simon','2015-02-20 10:33:48']])

df2.columns = ['name','datemax']

df2.datemax = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in df2.datemax]

df = df.merge(df2,how='left')

grouped = df.groupby('name')

grouped.apply(lambda x: random.choice([a for a in x['date'].values if a<x['datemax'].values[0]]))
```

Took 18 ms, I guess it should scale linearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.DataFrame.sample` like

```
In [697]: idx = df2.set_index('name').datemax

In [698]: (df1.groupby('name')
              .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.date < idx[x.name]].sample(1))
              .reset_index(drop=True))
Out[698]:
                 date   name
0 2015-04-01 21:36:55   Dave
1 2015-02-18 14:10:40   John
2 2014-12-18 00:15:02   Lisa
3 2014-12-16 19:53:53  Simon
```