# Sample Data Script Inquiry?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a script that takes a sample from an Excel file, and produces a sample from a sample data calculation. I'm trying to make sure the formula distributes the sample evenly between all unique categories, but I'm not entirely sure where to start.

```
import pandas as pd
import random 

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/bryanmccormack/Desktop/Test_Catalog.xlsx")
df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]

category_total = df2['Category'].nunique()
total_rows = len(df2.axes[0])


ss = (2.58**2)*(.5)*(1-.5)/.04**2
ss2 = 1+(ss-1/total_rows)
ss3 = ss/ss2
ss4 = round(ss3 * 1000)

category = ss4 / category_total

df3 = df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(category))
```

df3 has 3774 items, and the sample formula takes 999 items, but I'm getting this error: "ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'"

Any idea why my code is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Random selection per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472213/python-random-selection-per-group)

Comment: It does. I have updated the code above, but I'm getting an error indicating a value error.

Comment: That error indicates that you're trying to take a sample from one of the groups that's larger than the number of rows in that group. Without knowing your data, it's hard to know how to help further.