# How to randomly select fixed number of rows (if greater) per group else select all rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Example Dataframe:

```
    Name Group_Id
    AAA  1
    ABC  1
    BDF  1
    CCC  2
    XYZ  2
    DEF  3
```

How could I randomly select fixed number of rows for each `Group_Id`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128248/10927892) suggests a method to use:

```
df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(lambda x: x.sample(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it throws an error if there is any group which has less than `2` rows. I want to be able to select all rows in that case. `.head()` allows to do that but I want random samples and not the initial rows.

Say that I want max two random draws per `Group_Id`, I would get:

```
    Name Group_Id
    AAA  1
    BDF  1
    CCC  2
    XYZ  2
    DEF  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to sample only if you have more row:

```
n = 2
(df.groupby('Group_Id')
   .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n) if len(x)>n else x  )
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

You can also try shuffling the whole data and `groupby().head()`:

```
df.sample(frac=1).groupby('Group_Id').head(2)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Group_Id
5  DEF         3
0  AAA         1
2  BDF         1
3  CCC         2
4  XYZ         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle each subgroup and take the first n rows. It will automatically take the min of n or actual.

```
n=2
df2 = df.groupby('Group_Id').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1)[:n]).reset_index(drop=True)
```