# How to assign random values from one column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. With id and event dates. I want to assign any one random value out of present event dates to id.

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-17 |
| 1 | 2020-01-22 |
| 1 | 2020-01-11 |
| 1 | 2020-01-13 |
| 2 | 2020-01-17 |
| 2 | 2020-01-18 |
| 2 | 2020-01-23 |

Dataframe should look like this:

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-11 |
| 2 | 2020-01-18 |

Need to do it in python/pandas. Can you please help ?

Comment: I found another one and I post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472213/python-random-selection-per-group

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby with apply on the sample function.

```
df.groupby('Id').Date.apply(lambda x: x.smaple())
```