# Select random ordered sequence from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given an example dataframe which holds data such as that below:

```
ID Field_1 Field_2 Group
1    ABC     XYZ     B
2    BCD     ABF     B
3    EEJ     KYA     B
..
12   KAS     UUY     Z
13   OEP     PLO     Z
..
84   HJH     HIE     N
85   YSU     SAR     N
```

How can one get a random, **ordered** sequence, such that a call to this method/lambda with a desired sequence of `[B, Z, N, B]` would retrieve a random selection of rows to match this criteria?

I've seen previous answers which can get random rows from a sample based on the group - however the returned selection is not ordered. For example, a reference to this previous answer could be: [Python: Random selection per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472213/python-random-selection-per-group)

Comment: pick two from group b, one from z, and one from n. then sort according to the sequence

Comment: What about when the criteria cannot be satisfied? If criteria is [....,N,B] for instance, all B rows precede the the N ones.

Comment: @Learningisamess the order in the dataframe does not matter. If it clarifies things, we can assume that the dataframe ordering is also random - i.e. by calling `dataset.sample(frac=1, random_state=SEED).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

One simple method would be to generate a dictionary of groups and use a list comprehension with `sample` and `pandas.concat`:

```
order = ['B', 'Z', 'N', 'B']
d = dict(list(df.groupby('Group')))
df_sample = pd.concat([d[k].sample(1) for k in order])
```

output:

```
   ID Field_1 Field_2 Group
1   2     BCD     ABF     B
4  13     OEP     PLO     Z
5  84     HJH     HIE     N
2   3     EEJ     KYA     B
```

*NB. this will be sampling **with replacement***

Answer (score 1):

Filter rows in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) should be way without `groupby`:

```
order = ['B', 'Z', 'N', 'B']
df1 = pd.concat([df[df['Group'].eq(k)].sample(1) for k in order])
print (df1)
   ID Field_1 Field_2 Group
2   3     EEJ     KYA     B
4  13     OEP     PLO     Z
6  85     YSU     SAR     N
1   2     BCD     ABF     B
```