# Random sampling from a dataframe with different size inputs for all groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a dataframe like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'B1','B2','B3','B4','C1','C2'],
        'Type': [1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5],
        'Point': [10,6,8,2,5,6,4,1,7,8,8],      
     })
```

I can easily take a random sample from *"Name"* column by using the *"Point"* column as probabilities like :

```
np.random.choice(df["Name"],6 ,p=df["Point"] / df["Point"].sum(),replace=False)
# array(['C1', 'A1', 'C2', 'B1', 'A3', 'A2'], dtype=object)
```

Then, I wanted to make the same thing among with the different groups inside the *"Type"* column. Additionally, I wanted to take different sample sizes for each group. Fortunately,I achieved this by using a loop like,

```
sample_sizes = [4,2,1]
output = []
for count, i in enumerate(np.unique(df['Type'])):
    data= df[df['Type']==i]
    result = np.random.choice(data["Name"],sample_sizes[count] ,p=data["Point"] / data["Point"].sum(),replace=False)
    output.append(result)

# [array(['A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A5'], dtype=object),
# array(['B4', 'B1'], dtype=object),
# array(['C2'], dtype=object)]
```

My question is, How can I achieve such a thing by using pandas features like `group_by`, `apply` etc? There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472213/python-random-selection-per-group). But I couldn't adapt it to my case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `groupby.ngroup` method to assign group numbers. Then use this number to get the appropriate sample size for each group and use your custom function for each group.

```
gbobj = df.groupby('Type')
df['ngroup'] = gbobj.ngroup()
f = lambda data: np.random.choice(data["Name"], sample_sizes[data['ngroup'].iloc[0]], 
                                  p=data["Point"] / data["Point"].sum(),replace=False)
out = gbobj.apply(f)
```

Two samples:

```
Type
1    [A3, A5, A4, A1]
3            [B1, B2]
5                [C2]
dtype: object

Type
1    [A1, A5, A2, A3]
3            [B2, B4]
5                [C2]
dtype: object
```