# Randomly selecting a subset of rows from a pandas dataframe based on existing column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns and would like to randomly select an equal number of rows based on the values of specific column. I thought of using a df.groupby['...'] but it did not work. Here is an example:

[image: dataframe]

Assume that I would like to randomly select one row per GroupID, how can I accomplish this? For example, let's say I select one random row per GroupID, the result would yield the following:

[image: dataframe random selection]

such that it outputs a single row based on the values in GroupID. Assume, for example, that rows are sorted by GroupID (from asc to desc), then select an "n" number of rows from ones that pertain to GroupID 1, 2, 3, and so on. Any information would definitely be helpful.

Also, if I need to select a specific number of rows per GroupID (let's say 1 row for GroupID=100, 4 rows for GroupID=200, etc.), any ideas?

[update]
I made a minor revision or extension using the recommended answer below to selectively choose specific n values for each group using the following:

```py
samples = []
values = [1,  1,  2, ...]
index = 0
for group in df.GroupID.unique():
    s = df.loc[df.GroupID== group].sample(n=values[index ]).reset_index(drop=True)
    samples.append(s)
    index = index + 1
    
sample = pd.concat(samples, axis=0)
```

Comment: if you'd like to get an answer, it's probably a good idea to give a reproducible example as code.

Comment: have you first checked [Random selection per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472213/python-random-selection-per-group)?

Comment: I tried using this: df.groupby(['GroupID']).sample(n=1, replace=False)

Comment: and what did not work?

Comment: I used df.groupby(['GroupID']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(5)).reset_index(drop=True) and it worked. Thank you so much! I think I had a typo and the link you provided, helped me solve this problem. Thank You mozway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code snippet will work for you

```
samples = []
for group in df.GroupID.unique():
    s = df.loc[df.GroupID== group].sample(n=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    samples.append(s)
    
sample = pd.concat(samples, axis=0)
```

The code will take each 'GroupID' and sample observation from that subgroup.
You can concatenate the subsamples (with one GroupID) for the needed sample.